# How can I create a single RAID volume with a single HDD?

Tags: ssd, raid, specifications

I have an i7 3770k, Asus P8Z77-Pro and two drives. An SSD 120Gb and a regular HDD 500Gb.

I'm interesting in using the SSD with the Intel's Smart Response technology.

As [stated](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/sb/CS-032826.htm?wapkw=intel%20smart%20response%20technology) in the requirements:

- Intel® Z68/Z77/H77/Q77 Express Chipset-based desktop board
- Intel® Core™ Processor in the LGA 1155 package System BIOS with SATA mode set to RAID
- Intel Rapid Storage Technology software 10.5 version release or later
- **Single hard disk drive** or multiple drives in a **single RAID volume**
- Solid State Drive (SSD) with a minimum capacity of 18.6GB
- Operating system: Microsoft Windows Vista* (32-bit and 64-bit editions), Microsoft Windows 7* (32-bit and 64-bit editions)

How can I create a single RAID volume with a single HDD?

The raid utility (Intel Rapid Storage Technology rom utility) only allow me to create raid 0 with ~250Gb and Raid 1 with ~110Gb (which seem normal). No option to create a Single Raid Volume with a Single HDD. Also, If I remove the SSD the raid utility is not accessible.

Answer (score 4):

The core notion of RAID is to use multiple hard drives (to achieve different purposes depending on the type of RAID you want). RAID with a single drive just doesn't make any sense.

The Intel doc is a bit ambiguous, but it really says
(Single hard disk drive) **or** (multiple drives in a single RAID volume),
and not
(Single hard disk drive or multiple drives) **in** a single RAID volume.

Comment: That is something Intel says in the requirements. There must be a meaning behind it. Also, there are lots of Smart Response examples in the internet that use one HDD and an SSD.

Comment: @Odys RAID is about redundancy across disks. It makes no sense to create a single-disk JBOD 'array' or a degraded RAID1 array.

Comment: @Odys - what Intel are getting at is that the SSD can only be used against a single volume. That single volume can be a single, normal disk, or multiple disks presented as a single volume through RAID. It clearly says "or". There is no way of doing RAID on a single disk because the `A` in RAID indicates more than one (Array).

Comment: Using both your SSD and your *normal* drive in a RAID is possible (but in your case not useful at all, unless you want a mirrored set, but you'll lose a lot of space and probably speed). But your question is how to create a RAID using **a single drive**, which is simply not possible. The Intel doc is a bit ambiguous, but it really says "(Single hard disk drive) **or** (multiple drives in a single RAID volume)".

Comment: True, no such thing as a RAID without at least 2 disks. The intel tech writer was probably tired and QC just for signature-checks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be mis-reading what Intel have written:

> Single hard disk drive or multiple drives in a single RAID volume

This is ambiguous, because it could mean:

- Single Hard Disk Drive
- Multiple Drives in a Single RAID Volume

OR

- Single Hard Disk Drive OR Multiple Drives
- In a RAID Volume.

They mean the first one. It is impossible to do RAID on a single disk, because the `A` in RAID requires more than one.

What Intel is implying is that the SSD can be used against a single volume. That volume can be a RAID set, or a single normal disk.

Answer (score 0):

The "Multiple drives in a single RAID volume" could mean it does NOT have the capability of creating multiple RAID volumes.

A RAID volume and HDD are presented to the OS as the same thing, a block device.

So in the end, for simplicity, think of it as
`"Single Hard Disk Drive" OR  "Single RAID Volume"`